# Android gallery properties

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement the android gallery example from http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

I get this error int he following lines

Failed to load properties file for project 'HelloGallery'

The Application HelloGallery (process com.hellogallery) has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again.

How to resolve this issue .The code is shown below.

HelloGallery.java

```
package com.HelloGallery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.R.drawable;

 public class HelloGalleryActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
 g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

 g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(HelloGalleryActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 });


  }

  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 int mGalleryItemBackground;
 private Context mContext;

 private Integer[] mImageIds = {
    R.drawable.sample_1,
    R.drawable.sample_2,
    R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4,
    R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6,
    R.drawable.sample_7
 };

 public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
     mContext = c;
     TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
     mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
        R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
     a.recycle();
 }

 public int getCount() {
     return mImageIds.length;
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

     i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
     i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
     i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
     i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

     return i;
 }
  }
}
```

main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
<TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/hello"
  />
  <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/gallery"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

attrs.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="HelloGallery">
 <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

R.java

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
   *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package com.HelloGallery;

public final class R {
  public static final class attr {
  }
  public static final class drawable {
 public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
  }
  public static final class id {
 public static final int gallery=0x7f050000;
  }
  public static final class layout {
 public static final int main=0x7f030000;
  }
  public static final class string {
 public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
 public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
  }
  public static final class styleable {
 /** Attributes that can be used with a HelloGallery.
    <p>Includes the following attributes:</p>
    <table>
    <colgroup align="left" />
    <colgroup align="left" />
    <tr><th>Attribute</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    <tr><td><code>{@link #HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground com.HelloGallery:android_galleryItemBackground}</code></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
    @see #HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground
  */
 public static final int[] HelloGallery = {
     0x0101004c
 };
 /**
   <p>This symbol is the offset where the {@link com.HelloGallery.R.attr#android_galleryItemBackground}
   attribute's value can be found in the {@link #HelloGallery} array.
   @attr name android:android_galleryItemBackground
 */
 public static final int HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground = 0;
  };
 }
```

Comment: Which line is it being thrown on, and did you copy/reproduce all of the resources for the project etc?

Comment: There is no error as such.I am new to android and eclipse..The error log indicates the error as shown above

Comment: if you are using eclipse then the error will be output in the LogCat window that should tell you the line of the problem. Also you should step through the code using the "debug as" from your project, again if using eclipse.  The properties file is usually generated when you create the project and it has the android SDK level in it, not much else.  How did you create this project, did you load it or just copy/cut/paste it?

Answer (score 0):

you have given xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in both linear layout aswellas in gallery.. just give it in linear layout alone. may be this will be problem for loading your xml file.
if not please post your error occured in logcat window.